# Rename [mexican-citizens] to [mexican-nationals]

Tags: discussion, tagging, tag-renaming

Everyone born in Mexico is considered a Mexican National, and foreigners who have resided in Mexico for (typically) 5+ years, and fulfil a number of requirements, can obtain Mexican Nationality.  Mexican Nationals can after age 18 become Mexican Citizens, which confers additional rights, however Citizenship is not required to obtain passports, visas for other countries, and travel internationally.

Most government websites I've seen regarding travel permissions for Mexicans refer to Mexican Nationals (the US Trusted Traveler Program, for example).

A such, I believe the tag **[mexican-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mexican-citizens)** should be renamed to **[mexican-nationals](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mexican-nationals)** to fully include all Mexicans.

Comment: The tags have generally standardized on "citizen" instead of "national", even for countries where the two differ and where nationality (e.g. country on your passport) is more relevant to travelers than citizenship.  Probably because "citizen" is a more familiar term to most people, and is appropriate most of the time.  [Some people don't know what "national" means.](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/297931/what-is-the-meaning-of-national-as-in-e-g-australian-national).

Answer (score 3):

As of today, we have 112 mentions of "Mexican citizen" vs. 22 mentions of "Mexican national" in Google search on this website. As such "Mexican citizen" seems like a more appropriate tag to me given that we use it for all other countries. We can also reference Wikipedia which has been our standard in case of tag disputes and they use ["Mexican citizens"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_requirements_for_Mexican_citizens) in the context of travel.

However I've created a tag synonym between [mexican-nationals](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mexican-nationals) and [mexican-citizens](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mexican-citizens) in case someone does try to use it. I've also updated the tag info to reference `nationals` in addition to `citizens`.

Comment: Any chance the google search came up with more results because the existing questions have the Mexican Citizens tag already which is found in the search?

Comment: Citizens is appropriate on other country tags, because citizen is the word used in those countries, unlike in Mexico. Officially the correct term is Mexican National, which is what we should be using here.

Comment: @Midavalo no, its all based on [actual questions/answers](https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-1-e&q=site%3Atravel.stackexchange.com+%22mexican+citizen%22). We also never had anyone trying to use the mexican-national tag before I created the synonym.